# Trying to create a GUI using java but not able to implement them the way i wanted

Tags: java, swing, label, javax.swing.text

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class SQlUI {
public static void main(String[] args){
SQlUI user=new SQlUI();
user.go();
}
public void go(){   
//Creating a Frame
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
//Creating three Panels
JPanel panel0=new JPanel();
JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
JPanel panel2=new JPanel();

//Creating three Buttons
JButton button0=new JButton("INSERT");
JButton button1=new JButton("UPDATE");
JButton button2=new JButton("DELETE");

//Adding panel0 to the frame which contains three butoon objects
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,panel0);
panel0.add(button0);
panel0.add(button1);
panel0.add(button2);

//Creating four textbox
JTextField textbox0 = new JTextField(120);
JTextField textbox1 = new JTextField(120);
JTextField textbox2 = new JTextField(120);
JTextField textbox3 = new JTextField(120);

//Adding panel1 to the frame which contains four textbox objects
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,panel1);
//Using BoxLayout managaer for panel1 objects
panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
panel1.add(textbox0);
panel1.add(textbox1);
panel1.add(textbox2);
panel1.add(textbox3);

//Adding panel2 to the frame which contains four label objects
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST,panel2);
//Using BoxLayout managaer for panel1 objects
panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

//Creating four labels 
JLabel label0=new JLabel("Name");
label0.setSize(50,50);
label0.setVisible(true);
JLabel label1=new JLabel("ID");
label1.setSize(50,50);
label1.setVisible(true);
JLabel label2=new JLabel("AGE");
label2.setSize(50,50);
label2.setVisible(true);
JLabel label3=new JLabel("ADDRESS");
label3.setSize(50,50);
label3.setVisible(true);
//Adding labels to panel2
panel2.add(label0);
panel2.add(label1);
panel2.add(label2);
panel2.add(label3);

//Setting frame size and visiblity
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}
```

Details about the GUI- I am trying to create a GUI which have four textbox where user can enter his details and there are three buttons available on GUI by which user can send the data or store the data. The GUI also contains labels which tells the user which textbox is for which type of data. 
                        Now the allignment of the objects are not coming the way i wanted it. All the labels are coming at one place and the size of box is very big. Tried to find a solution on stalkoverflow but got nothing.

i want something like this----
Name- textbox0
ID- textbox1
AGE- textbox2
ADDRESS- textbox3

Insert  Update Delete

but getting something like----
                         textbox0

```
                     textbox1
```

Name
ID
AGE
Address                  textbox2

```
                     textbox3

      Insert   Update   Delete
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the `BoxLayout`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using indentations in your code?

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,panel0);` can't be working, your arguments are interchanged.

Comment: @user1803551 sir could u please me what indentations means

Comment: @Sarah Tattersall Yes i am intentionally using BoxLayout in my code because i wanted only one text box in one row. If i am not using BoxLayout manager then all the four text boxes comes in a single row one after another.

Comment: Indentations is when you put spaces in front of lines to make the code readable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: @user1803551 I was not knowing about Indentations thats why i did't use them in my codes. But from now onward i will use them. Do u have any idea how i can put one label before one textbox. Like name= textbox0

Comment: I'll post an answer, but you have to correct `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,panel0);`. Read what this method does.

Comment: @user1803551 Tried everything but not getting any solution. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best looking thing you can do, but it's simple and a good start for you.

```
public class SQlUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SQlUI user = new SQlUI();
        user.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton insert = new JButton("INSERT");
        JButton update = new JButton("UPDATE");
        JButton delete = new JButton("DELETE");
        buttonsPanel.add(insert);
        buttonsPanel.add(update);
        buttonsPanel.add(delete);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(120);
        namePanel.add(nameLabel);
        namePanel.add(nameField);

        JPanel idPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("ID");
        JTextField idField = new JTextField(120);
        idPanel.add(idLabel);
        idPanel.add(idField);

        centerPanel.add(namePanel);
        centerPanel.add(idPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

- Notice that I call `frame.getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` with the panel as the first argument and the position second, you did it the other way around.
- Not sure why you need text fields of length 120.
- Call `frame.pack()` instead of setting the size yourself.
- See what indentation does to the code.
- You can complete the rest of the panels by yourself.

Comment: Sir i am a beginner in java programming. Thereis no specific reason of using 120 as textfeild length. I used frame.pack(); instead of setting the size by myself and it did worked for my existing code without doing any modification. I learned many things from your code but most important was frame.pack(). From now onwards i will try to write code in your style so that i can avoid complications.(Like i have crated four pannels but all panel contain same kind of object. You have also created 2 pannels but they contains four different type of object.)

Comment: What is the different between using [frame.getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);] and [frame.getContentPane().add( BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonsPanel);] ?

Comment: @Shantanu Look at the [API for Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) under Method Summary and tell me yourself what's the difference.

Comment: As per my understanding the order in which i will pass the  argument in Container it will displayed in the same way. For example if i pass argument (name, id , age , address) in this order it will be displayed  that way. If i pass the argument in reverse order like(address,age,id,name) then it will be displayed in this order. Am i correct?

Comment: @Shantanu Look at the function `add`, then look which type of parameters you pass to it and deduce which of the `add` methods was called. Then look at the description and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up on different layouts [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). It'll give you more of an idea how you can lay your items out. You can then experiment to find out which one you actually want.

That said I find it far easier to design a GUI graphically, and IntelliJ has [a pretty good GUI builder](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html) that I've often used. You'll then be able to play around with layout managers and JPanels to get the effect you actually want.